# Parse htmltags from a string java/gwt

Tags: java, html, string, parsing, gwt

Hey I want to parse some data from html that I get sent to me in a string. 
I the data i want is in UPPERCASE and i will name it DATAx here.
The lenght of the data is arbitrary.

http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1270216

there are many more lines like this that i have to parse.

thx for answears!

Comment: You'll need to provide some more information on the type of data you're trying to extract from this String, calling it `DATAx` is not helpful in this situation.  Also without delimiters (like a comma between each piece of data) this could be very difficult.

Comment: trying to get the code in to the post :)

Comment: Its strings and doubles i want to get from the html

Answer (score 2):

I've had great luck with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It uses a jQuery style dom node selector and can work with HTML fragments, even very poorly formatted ones.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string i can get the plain text from different ids and tags?

Comment: @Alb - Yes. Walk through the examples. Specifically, this one: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jsoup, but [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) is a fantastic HTML-parsing library. I've had it in a production system for a couple of years now which has been run against tens of thousands (at least) of web pages in the wild, and we've never had a single failure from TagSoup. It handles even the most horribly formatted HTML imaginable.